# getting text caret position from Cocoa based application

Tags: objective-c, shell, cocoa, applescript

I have a Cocoa based application on it that has a canvas inside a 'ScrollArea' where you can type text. I need to get the text caret position (position where the next text will be typed) from this application. Keeping in mind that I am outside the application, i.e. I have no access to the code of this application. I am basically automating some black box tests on this application. I can use Objective-c, outside applications, applescript, shell script, anything.
[image: This is what the Accessibility Inspector panel looks like at my current position]

I have tried to use this but it doesn't work because the canvas in my application is not a text area, it's a scroll view:

```
    AXUIElementRef systemWideElement = AXUIElementCreateSystemWide();
    AXUIElementRef focussedElement = NULL;
    AXError error = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(systemWideElement,                kAXFocusedUIElementAttribute, (CFTypeRef *)&focussedElement);
    if (error != kAXErrorSuccess) {
NSLog(@"Could not get focussed element");
    } else {
        AXValueRef selectedRangeValue = NULL;
        AXError getSelectedRangeError =     AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(focussedElement,   kAXSelectedTextRangeAttribute, (CFTypeRef *)&selectedRangeValue);
        if (getSelectedRangeError == kAXErrorSuccess) {
            CFRange selectedRange;
            AXValueGetValue(selectedRangeValue, kAXValueCFRangeType, &selectedRange);
            AXValueRef selectionBoundsValue = NULL;
            AXError getSelectionBoundsError =     AXUIElementCopyParameterizedAttributeValue(focussedElement, kAXBoundsForRangeParameterizedAttribute, selectedRangeValue, (CFTypeRef *)&selectionBoundsValue);
            CFRelease(selectedRangeValue);
            if (getSelectionBoundsError == kAXErrorSuccess) {
                CGRect selectionBounds;
                AXValueGetValue(selectionBoundsValue, kAXValueCGRectType, &selectionBounds);
                NSLog(@"Selection bounds: %@", NSStringFromRect(NSRectFromCGRect(selectionBounds)));
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Could not get bounds for selected range");
            }
            if (selectionBoundsValue != NULL)   CFRelease(selectionBoundsValue);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Could not get selected range");
        }
    }
    if (focussedElement != NULL) CFRelease(focussedElement);
    CFRelease(systemWideElement);
```

Please suggest something else.

Comment: Do you see the insertion point in the attributes in the Accessibility Inspector panel?

Comment: Yes, I did. I am adding the picture of the Accessibility Inspector panel.

Comment: Is `focussedElement` the scroll area? The selected range isn't an attribute of the scroll area.

Comment: Yes it is. And I understand, but what do I do to get my selected text from this kind of application. In this app, the scroll area contains a kind of a drawing canvas and the text is on it and the accessibility values on the text is as shown in the image

Comment: Apparently the canvas isn't accessible.